# Gravity Forms & Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've successfully created the dropdown menu to auto populate the appropriate information from an Advanced Custom Field I created called 'date' on site http://albertson.staging.wpengine.com/seminars/.

Followed along with the instructions here:

http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Dynamically_Populating_Drop_Down_Fields

The only issue I'm having is how to display the date in a "pretty" format. You can see that the date is all numbers (20140129) instead of 01/28/2014

To display the date appropriately in the seminar sections above (border red) I use:

```
<?php if( get_field('date')): ?>

<?php
$date = get_field('date');
// $date = 19881123 (23/11/1988)

// extract Y,M,D
$y = substr($date, 0, 4);
$m = substr($date, 4, 2);
$d = substr($date, 6, 2);

// create UNIX
$time = strtotime("{$d}-{$m}-{$y}");

// format date (November 11th 1988)
echo date('M d', $time);
?>
```

How do I pass this same information within the Gravity Forms Function I created to get the date to display nicely? Below is my function for Gravity Forms so far.

```
    add_filter('gform_pre_render_4', 'populate_dates');

function populate_dates($form){

    foreach($form['fields'] as &$field){

        if($field['type'] != 'select' || strpos($field['cssClass'], 'populate-dates') === false)
            continue;

        // you can add additional parameters here to alter the posts that are retreieved
        // more info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts
        $currentdate = date("Y-m-d",mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d"),date("Y")));

        $events = get_posts(array(
                    'post_type' => 'seminars',
                    'orderby' => 'date',
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    'meta_query'=> array(
                        array(
                          'key' => 'date',
                          'compare' => '>=',
                          'value' => $currentdate,
                          'type' => 'DATE',
                        )),
                    'meta_key' => 'date',
                    ));  

        // update 'Select a Post' to whatever you'd like the instructive option to be
        $choices = array(array('text' => 'Select a Date', 'value' => ' '));

        foreach($events as $post){
            $choices[] = array('text' => $post->date, 'value' => $post->date);

        }

        $field['choices'] = $choices;

    }

    return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for PHP's [date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function. We convert the date string to a timestamp via strtotime() and then use date() to format the date as you wish.

```
$formatted_date = date( 'm/d/Y', strtotime( $post->date ) );
```

In your code example:

```
foreach( $events as $post ){
    $formatted_date = date( 'm/d/Y', strtotime( $post->date ) );
    $choices[] = array('text' => $formatted_date, 'value' => $post->date );
}
```